# Can I redirect all IE8 users for all sites on a server?

Tags: windows, redirect, iis-7, internet-explorer-8

I have W2008 running IIS and have about 20 websites (all PHP, about half are WP) running on it.

Currently I have this in the header on a few sites and it is working.  But it is getting hard to manage because even though I am the admin there are a lot of developers and they could overwrite the header if they wanted on most sites.

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
<script type="text/javascript">
        window.location = "http://example.com/wedontsupportIE8.html";
    </script>
<![endif]-->
```

Is there a way to set up a rule on the server that would have the same functionality?

**ADDED NOTE:**

I have added rules on web server and they basically don't work right.  I had the redirect to /home/index.php already working for the past 6 months.  When I add the new rule first it does the following:

- in IE8 - 404 error for any directory on site and it reverts to the root
- in IE10, FF, Chrome, Safari - it just redirects to /home as it should.

webconfig below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
  <rule name="IE8rewriteall" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
                    <match url="*" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="*MSIE*" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://example.com/ie/index.html" />
                </rule>
            <rule name="Root Hit Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^$" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="/home/index.php" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Kinda bad practice to redirect them away to a different site.  You might be better off keeping this on the client side (via javascript) but instead of a redirect actually overlaying the screen with a div and then a link to upgrade their browser.

Comment: @Frank - I agree but it is just a big intranet site and this is what they want.  The redirect has links to upgrade and different browsers to choose from.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it. Have to install a iis7 plugin URL Rewriter though. IIS7 OOB can't do it.

[URL Rewriter](http://halcoberry.blogspot.com/2012/05/how-to-redirect-specific-browser-in-ii7.html)

Hope this helps

Comment: I did this as the example shows (was fine to test that all IE gets redirected).  It doesn't seem to be working unless I messed something up.  I added note to question with more info.